# making media URL secured

Tags: uploads, media, security

I am working on a project in which all the media files should be secured and can be only visible to logged in users.

**Stop Sharing Media using Absolute URL**

If one people copy the media url and paste it to different user it should not be accessible directly. The user who has uploaded his image can only view. others cannot.

**Blocking Absolute URL**

If we will block `http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/hello.jpg` , then will `the_post_thumbnail()` will work and display, as in this function it uses the `absolute URL`. Should we use relative URL of image to display in `<img src="">`.

**Rewrite Rule for Attachment**

Is it possible to make something like 
`http://www.example.com/lorem/ipsum/?id=34` where 34 will be attachment id and from here we can view the content. And the people who upload this should be able to view it and no one else.

**Sharing Media Functionality **

If the user wants to share his image he can create a share url from where the media can be displayed and that share url should be destroyed after some interval of time.
Eg : I want to share my image whose id= 34 . `URL as http://www.example.com/lorem/ipsum/?id=34`, but the share url should not be 
the same as `http://www.example.com/lorem/ipsum/?id=34` , it should be like `http://www.example.com/share?id=99`.

#### Should I use WP for this or should I prefer other PHP framework.

Thanks

Comment: Are you also destroying the media after the timeframe?

Comment: No, media file will be there always. If it is deleted by owner then it should be removed.

Comment: not sure what is the question here. you can implement any media handling you wish, the main problem with that will be that you will need to implement it yourself